# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException after migrating to androidx in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, androidx

I recently migrated my example project to androidx. But, after migration, it causes 'Render Problem' in the preview. The project runs, nevertheless, but it would be helpful to get the preview working again.

As stated in the title, the render problem is caused by "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke". A snippet is provided below.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@1a8e42ac
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor990.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:143)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1387)
at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction(ValueAnimator.java:674)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:637)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1069)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1088)
at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:852)
at android.animation.StateListAnimator.start(StateListAnimator.java:188)
at android.animation.StateListAnimator.setState(StateListAnimator.java:181)
at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:21105)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawableStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:7101)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.drawableStateChanged(AppBarLayout.java:393)
at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:21160)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:18379)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3397)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:335)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:391)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:195)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:540)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$5(RenderTask.java:666)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is my layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tabs">

            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</merge>
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.materialdemo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-beta01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.instabug.library:instabug:8.0.15.6-SNAPSHOT'


}
```

My project level build.gradle file:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common 
to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }

        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }

        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven/"
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: I'm revisiting this question after a long time haha....but no I never found a proper solution. I just ended up recreating the entire project and reused some of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Going back to `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` and invalidating the caches via `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...` works for me.

Also, any other theme like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` works great, too.

**Edit:** I did not know that nearly no feature available in `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06` is available in 1.0.0. So this answer is more or less useless.